# How does this custom route matcher in Sinatra example work?

Tags: ruby, routes, sinatra

In the [Sinatra README](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html), there is a section called [Custom Route Matchers](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Custom%20Route%20Matchers) with the following example:

```
class AllButPattern
  Match = Struct.new(:captures)

  def initialize(except)
    @except   = except
    @captures = Match.new([])
  end

  def match(str)
    @captures unless @except === str
  end
end

def all_but(pattern)
  AllButPattern.new(pattern)
end

get all_but("/index") do
  # ...
end
```

Would anyone be helpful enough to talk me through how this works? The bit I'm not sure about is why the example has the `Match` struct and what `captures` are. The user can't set the `@captures` instance variable, just the `@except` one; so how is `captures` used?

Comment: ... `@captures` holds the "match everything" class that acts-like something with a `captures` method. It's returned unless the string matches precisely what's passed in the constructor. I mean, there isn't a lot going on here.

Comment: it is pretty much a wildcard that you can exceptions to.  Do you want to know how the mechanics of how it works?

Comment: That would be great @Doon.

Comment: Would you be able to expand on that @DaveNewton?

Comment: It's not clear to me where the confusion lies; what specifically don't you understand about it?

Comment: Why `captures` is there and how Sinatra uses it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[When a route is processed, it takes the argument to `get` (or `post` or whatever), and sends to that object's `match` method with the path as an argument](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L996). It expects back either `nil` which would mean it didn't match, or an array of captures. The object is usually a string or a regex and they both have a `match` method.

[Sinatra also calls on the `captures` method of the object when it is processing a route](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L997). The example uses a struct as an easy way to set up and respond with an object that itself will respond to `captures`, and puts in an array, as that's what `captures` would usually return. It's empty because the string hasn't been checked for captures, it's really a negative filter. As such, I'd prefer [the use of a `before` filter](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Filters) to do something like this, but finding clear and useful examples is always difficult.